# Java Issue with replace spaces using regex

Tags: java, regex

This is for a fraction class.  When i test the fraction class with a string like "2/4" I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".
```

I think it has something to do with the sStringTo method when trying to replace spaces.

```
public class Util{

static int findGCF(int a, int b){
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);
    while(a != b){
        if (a>b) a = a-b; else b = b-a;
    }
    return (a);
}

static Fraction sIntTo(String s){ //"2"
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return new Fraction(n);
}

static Fraction sFractionTo(String s){ //"2/3"
    s = s.trim();

    int posSlash = s.indexOf("/");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,posSlash));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(posSlash + 1));
    return new Fraction(n,m);
}

static Fraction sMixTo(String s){
    s =s.trim();
    int posB = s.indexOf(" ");
    int posSlash = s.indexOf("/");
    int w = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,posB));
    int t = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(posB+1, posSlash));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(posSlash+1));
    return new Fraction(w*b+t,b);
}

static Fraction sDecTo(String s){
    s = s.trim();
    int i = s.indexOf(".");

    String sub = s.substring(i+1);

    String sNoPeriod = s.substring(0,i) + sub;

    int top = Integer.parseInt(sNoPeriod);
    int bot = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j<sub.length(); j++) bot = bot*10;
    return new Fraction(top,bot);
}
static Fraction divFraction(Fraction f, Fraction g){
    return new Fraction (f.num * g.den, f.den * g.num);
}

static Fraction addFraction(Fraction f, Fraction g){
    return new Fraction (f.num * g.den + f.den * g.num, f.den*g.den);
}

static Fraction sStringTo(String s){
    s=s.trim();
    s= s.replaceAll("\\s*/\\S*", "/");// remove 0 or more blanks before & after slash
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); // all blanks to be one blank:  2   1/2

    int posB = s.indexOf(" ");
    int posSlash = s.indexOf("/");
    int posPed = s.indexOf(".");

    Fraction ans = null;

    if(posB>-1){
        if (posSlash>posB) { ans = sMixTo(s);}
    }else{
        if (posPed == -1 && posSlash == -1) ans = sIntTo(s); //integer only
        else{
            if(posSlash == -1) ans = sDecTo(s);// decimal only
            else{
                //with slash "2.1/2 2.1/2.1
                Fraction f = sStringTo(s.substring(0,posSlash));
                Fraction g = sStringTo(s.substring(posSlash+1));
                ans = divFraction(f,g);
            }
        }

    }
    return ans;
}//sStringTo()
```

The problematic stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Util.sIntTo(Util.java:17)
at Util.sStringTo(Util.java:75)
at Util.sStringTo(Util.java:81)
at Fraction.<init>(Fraction.java:31)
at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: can you post the definition of sIntTo? According to your stack trace, the issue is in that function.

Comment: i added the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a string containing only whitespace into `sIntTo()`. You should consider just removing all whitespace, rather than just reducing it to a single space. Consider changing `s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` to `s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");`.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem.  It was a syntax error on my part.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\s*/\\S*", "/");`, right? :) by the way, the downvote is not mine